# Reverse sorting of arrays

Tags: c#, object, arraylist

I'm having trouble sorting this list of objects in reverse, the below code works well in ascending order.

```
DC d = new DC();   
var t = d.GetList();
t.Sort((s1, s2) => DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(s.time),DateTime.Parse(s.time)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine if you flip them round.

```
DC d = new DC();   
var t = d.GetList();
t.Sort((s1, s2) => DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(s2.time),DateTime.Parse(s1.time)));
```

Although note also that you are using s.time in both as opposed to `s1.time` and `s2.time`.